# MongoDB object id issue in json output

Tags: php, json, mongodb, phalcon

I using have to read some data from `MongoDB` via `PHP`.
When i converting `MongoDB` result to `Json`, i getting a result like below :

```
{    
    "records":
    [            
        {
            "_id":
            {
                "id": "567f18f21e2e328206d3d91e"
            },
            "title": "test",
            "price": 5000,
            "date": "1394-09-05 11:30",
            "images":
            [
                {
                    "_id":
                    {
                        "id": "567f18f21e2e328206d3d91f"
                    },
                    "url": "a"
                },
                {
                    "_id":
                    {
                        "id": "567f18f21e2e328206d3d920"
                    },
                    "url": "x"
                },
                {
                    "_id":
                    {
                        "id": "567f18f21e2e328206d3d921"
                    },
                    "url": "c"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see we have a id like below :

```
"_id":
 {
     "$id": "567f18f21e2e328206d3d91e"
  },
```

And it cause some problem for me when i want to parse this json in Java, **i want to convert this to something like this :**

```
{    
    "records":
    [
        {

            "id": "567f18f21e2e328206d3d91e"           
            "title": "test",
            "price": 5000,
            "date": "1394-09-05 11:30",
            "images":
            [
                {
                    "id": "567f18f21e2e328206d3d91f",
                    "url": "a"
                },
                {
                    "id": "567f18f21e2e328206d3d920",
                    "url": "x"
                },
                {
                    "id": "567f18f21e2e328206d3d921",
                    "url": "c"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

How can i do this?
I cannot use `foreach` method in order to edit this array, because i have unlimited sub arrays

Answer (score 1):

First [decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) the json data and convert it to array. From the converted array then you can format your expected pattern. [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) can help you.

```
$data = json_decode($old_json_data, true);

$new_data_format = [];
if(isset($data['records'])){
    $data = $data['records'];
    $new_data_format = array_map(function($val){
        return [
            'id' => $val['_id']['id'],
            'title' => $val['title'],
            'price' => $val['price'],
            'date' => $val['date'],
            'images' => array_map(function($v){
                return [
                    'id' => $v['_id']['id'],
                    'url' => $v['url'],
                ];
            }, $val['images'])
        ];
    }, $data);
}

$new_data_format = json_encode(['records' => $new_data_format]);
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks very much, but as i mentioned i have unlimited sub array int this array and all of them have "_id" and i should replace them. it was just a sample.

Comment: is this possible to do this with recursive function?

Comment: @AliHasanzade, what is the reason for avoiding a recursive function?